# Outputting content from an xml file using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, parsing, jquery-selectors

I'm having some trouble with a jquery script I'm writing, as I cannot get it to fetch the data I want.

I have an xml file of the following sort of layout (I'm presenting a fragment only),

```
<page1>
  <title>First page</title>
  <description>Lorem ipsum</description>
  <image1 thumb='#'>images/image01.jpg</image1>
  <image2 thumb ='#'>images/image02.jpg</image2>
</page1>
<page2>
  <title>Second page</title>
  <description>Lorem ipsum</description>
  <image1 thumb='#'>images/image01.jpg</image1>
  <image2 thumb ='#'>images/image02.jpg</image2>
</page2>
```

Now I want to find a way of fetching the description depending on the title value.  My code is as folows and I can tell that something is horribly wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "xml_concept.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: parseXml
  });  
});

function parseXml(xml) {
  $(xml).find("title":contains("First Page")) {
    $("#text-area").append('<div class="test-xml">' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the this is not referring to what I want, but rather the xml as a whole?  If correct, how can I select the content of the tags I'm after and append them?  I have been able to parse content successfully but not with the sort of conditions I'm setting, so I was thinking of using if statements or case/switch.

Another thing, am I right in assuming that I've used the ':contains' totally wrong?

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more suitable way of achieving the results I desired by loading external html content direct instead of relying on one xml doc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
$(xml).find("Title":contains("O2 Brandroom"))
```

...specifically the colon after `"Title"`, which is invalid Javascript syntax.

The intention of this code is for the `contains()` bit to be a part of the same selector as `Title`, so try putting the whole thing inside quotes:

```
$(xml).find("Title:contains('O2 Brandroom')")
```

Comment: Thanks.  That makese sense.  However, the data still isn't showing up in my html.  Now the second line of code has worked fine with other takes, I'm wondering now if $(this).text() is actually retrieving the content of that 'title' tag.  Please note that I've changed O2 Brandroom to First Page as in my example, and 'Title' to 'title' as it is in my xml